# How to cancel web service request within task, and do some stuff when cancel happened

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellation

We have a tree, and when user click on any node, it will query data from web service, and displace the result. However, sometimes it take times. So I try to wrap the web service call in a task. I would like cancel the task when it hasn't finished and user click to the other nodes. The following is my sample code. However the cancel task block can't be execute, even the _cancelTokenSource.Cancel() execute. Most of samples provided by MSDN are based on CPU bound, not I/O bound. Can anyone tell me how to cancel a web service all? Thanks in advance

```
private void OnNodeClicked(int id)
{
 if (_cancelTokenSource != null)
     _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();

 IsRunning = true;
 var uiSchedule = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
 _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
 var loadDataTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew<int[]>(() =>
 {
     // Call web service here
 }, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

 loadDataTask.ContinueWith((result) =>
 {
     // Populate data
     IsRunning = false;
 }, CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, uiSchedule);

 loadDataTask.ContinueWith((result) =>
 {
     // set cancel state here
     IsRunning = false;
 }, CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, uiSchedule);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`CancellationTokenSource` and its token are a way for one thread (or task) to query whether another thread is requestion the task cancel.  This, of course, requires you write code that checks that token (and therefore be run at least once, and typically periodically).  If you've delegated off to some generated code (the web service proxy) that doesn't know anything about Task or cancellation tokens, then you can't use that.

If you used the Begin method to start the call, then you can use `WebClientAsyncResult.Abort()` to abort the call.  e.g.:

```
IAsyncResult ar = obj.BeginFunCall(5,5,null,null);
//...
if (!ar.IsCompleted) //if the request is not completed  { 
  WebClientAsyncResult wcar = (WebClientAsyncResult)ar;
  wcar.Abort();//abort the call to web service 
}
```